# Cant connect IPv6 linux server via Putty

Tags: ipv6

Cant connect IPv6 linux server via Putty.
Server IP should be like this: 2001:14c0:2:2f6f::6

But when i replace working IPv4 in my putty by this address, it dont connect returning: Unable to open connection to MYIPv6 Host does not exist

Please which files to check, commands to do to make IPv6 ssh connection working?

---

In /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts ssh config, I have:

```
Port 22
AddressFamily any
ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
ListenAddress ::
```

ping6 ipv6.google.com works

ping myipv6::6 works too

ping myipv6::1 works too (received, no packet loss)

traceroute6 google.com works too

Comment: You have a routing problem at your end, according to ping6 and traceroute6. Post your complete IPv6 configuration, and the details of what the configuration is meant to be.

Answer (score 8):

You should input the IPv6 address between brackets, like this:

[2001:14c0:2:2f6f::6]

then it will work.

Comment: That notation is used if the IP address is in a URL. But I have never seen it used for ssh. Does PuTTY differ that much from other ssh clients?

Comment: I had to add "%wlan0" onto the end of mine (IIRC this is called something like "specifying an interface)

Comment: @donbright That is only for link-local addresses. The address in this question is not link-local.